# Group (by year) and sum in javascript collection

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to sum the values of the same year in a single value for each year, in a node javascript application. I would like to avoid a for(;;) iteration, discovering the year, sum the values....
 Maybe there is something in the Underscore library (like _.groupBy but I cannot figure how use it in this case).
The json data is this (i.e quarterly income data):

```
{ "data":
 ["2015-07-22",125677000000.0],
 ["2015-04-28",129006000000.0],
 ["2015-01-28",123328000000.0],
 ["2014-10-27",111547000000.0],
 ["2014-07-23",120940000000.0],
 ["2014-04-24",120178999999.99998],
 ["2014-01-28",129684000000.0],
 ["2013-10-30",123549000000.0],
 ["2013-07-24",123354000000.00002],
 ["2013-04-24",135490000000.0],
 ["2013-01-24",127346000000.0],
 ["2012-10-31",118210000000.0],
 [etc...]}
```

the result should be:

```
 { "data":
 ["2015",sum of all 2015 data],
 ["2014",sum of all 2014 data],
 ["2013",sum of all 2013 data],
 [etc...]}
```

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to avoid using a loop?

Comment: you cant avoid loop.. if you use framework so this framework will use loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem at all, no loops, no underscore needed.

```
a = { "data":[
 ["2015-07-22",125677000000.0],
 ["2015-04-28",129006000000.0],
 ["2015-01-28",123328000000.0],
 ["2014-10-27",111547000000.0],
 ["2014-07-23",120940000000.0],
 ["2014-04-24",120178999999.99998],
 ["2014-01-28",129684000000.0],
 ["2013-10-30",123549000000.0],
 ["2013-07-24",123354000000.00002],
 ["2013-04-24",135490000000.0],
 ["2013-01-24",127346000000.0],
 ["2012-10-31",118210000000.0]]}


var years = a.data.map(function(d) {
    return [new Date(d[0]).getFullYear(), d[1]];
 });

var sums = years.reduce(function(prev, curr, idx, arr) {
    var sum = prev[curr[0]];
    prev[curr[0]] = sum ? sum + curr[1] : curr[1];
    return prev; 
 }, {});

> sums
Object {2012: 118210000000, 2013: 509739000000, 2014: 482350000000, 2015: 378011000000}
```

Note that I had to fix your JSON data. The one you posted wasn't valid JSON, so I just added array brackets around the list of lists.

You can even do it in 1 line if you want.

```
a.data.map(function(d) { return [new Date(d[0]).getFullYear(), d[1]]; }).reduce(function(prev, curr, idx, arr) { var sum = prev[curr[0]]; prev[curr[0]] = sum ? sum + curr[1] : curr[1]; return prev; }, {});
```

Just kidding, please don't do that :)

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions, I would say this is the one I prefer (and the map-reduce I was looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Now that you mention underscore, iterating once and calling the indexes do it

```
var json = { "data":   [["2015-07-22",125677000000.0],  ["2015-04-28",129006000000.0],  ["2015-01-28",123328000000.0],  ["2014-10-27",111547000000.0],  ["2014-07-23",120940000000.0],  ["2014-04-24",120178999999.99998],  ["2014-01-28",129684000000.0],  ["2013-10-30",123549000000.0],  ["2013-07-24",123354000000.00002],  ["2013-04-24",135490000000.0],  ["2013-01-24",127346000000.0],  ["2012-10-31",118210000000.0]]
           };

var sums = {};

_.each(json.data, function(arr) { 
    var index = arr[0].split('-')[0];
    if (typeof(sums[index]) !== 'undefined') {
        sums[index] += arr[1];
    } else {
        sums[index] = arr[1];
    } });
```

And yes, as @bbill points out, I fix your JSON as well :)

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6bLf67t/) for it

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
    ["2015-07-22",125677000000.0],
    ["2015-04-28",129006000000.0],
    ["2015-01-28",123328000000.0],
    ["2014-10-27",111547000000.0],
    ["2014-07-23",120940000000.0],
    ["2014-04-24",120178999999.99998],
    ["2014-01-28",129684000000.0],
    ["2013-10-30",123549000000.0],
    ["2013-07-24",123354000000.00002],
    ["2013-04-24",135490000000.0],
    ["2013-01-24",127346000000.0],
    ["2012-10-31",118210000000.0]
];
```

Create the sums in a map (years -> sums) - then turn the map into an array with `_.pairs`:

```
var result = _.pairs(data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    var year = curr[0].substr(0, 4);
    prev[year] = prev[year] ? prev[year] + curr[1] : curr[1];
    return prev;
}, {}));
```

Then order by first element, descending:

```
result.sort(function(a, b) { return a[0] < a[1]; });
```